# Multiplatform (Win, Mac, Linux) development environment to achieve native look-and-feel? (Just as Dropbox)

Tags: dropbox, multiplatform

I've noticed that all betas for Dropbox are released simultaneously for Windows, Mac and Linux. How do they do that? Anyone knows which platform they're using? I'm aware that there are many native -very impressive, actually- functions in each of the platform clients, but they seem to release critical bug fixes efortlessly for all platforms.

So any idea of which GUI platform they're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linux version includes files such as `wx._windows_.so`, `libwx_gtk2*.so`, etc. (I haven't checked the others), so I suspect Dropbox uses [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/).

Answer (score 3):

[Qt](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/) is a popular cross-platform application and GUI framework with native look-and-feel.

I don't know what Dropbox uses for all its supported platforms, but it looks like its linux client uses at least [Gtk](http://www.gtk.org/):  Dropbox linux [System Requirements](http://www.getdropbox.com/downloading?os=lnx).